# C - shift power operation

Tags: c

Since I am new to C probably i have not clear how to use correctly the shift operator.
I wrote this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define SIZE 8

int main() {
    int a[ SIZE ] = {0};
    int i;
    int x = 1;
    int sum = 0;
    for (i = (SIZE - 1); i >= 0; i--){
        scanf("%d", &a[ i ]);
    }
    for (i = 0;i < SIZE;i++) {
        if (x & a[ i ])
            sum = sum + (i << 1);
        else
            sum = (sum + 0); 
    }
    printf ("%d\n\n", sum);
    return 0;
}
```

What i expect from this code is that if i enter in the stack this values:

```
0
0
0
0
0
0
1
1
```

it returns to me the result of power of two of the index of the array.
This would be that index 0 is shifted of one bit left to 1 and index 1 is shifted of one bit left to 2.

Then the values are stored in sum variable and once the cycle ends, printf gives the total sum to me which should be 3 in this case. But the value returned is 2 instead.

If I enter :

```
1
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
```

the value returned is 14.

So it seems to me that the it just multiply by two the input. I don`t understand what i am doing wrong.

Comment: `else sum = (sum + 0); ` does absolutely nothing in this program. It leaves `sum` unchanged and has no side effects.

Comment: You are new to `C`, so this should be said. Indent your code blocks. You'll thank yourself later when it's longer than a few lines.

Comment: what you're trying to do isn't really clea

Comment: Think about what gets aded to `sum` when `i` has the value `3` and you have entered an odd number into `a[3]`.

Comment: Shifting signed integers can be problematic. Some values invoke _undefined behaviour_ (left shift) resp. are implementation defined (right shift). In general it is better to use only unsigned integers. And have a look at more C code. You rusage of spaces in the code is - well - creative.

Comment: You have `(i << 1)` backwards.  You want `(1 << i)`.

Comment: Ok thanks to everybody for the suggestions guys.
@Logicrat i know the else doesn`t nothing
@Tom Yes you are right that was my error i will need time to reflect about the two use cases but thanks a lot. Now the program do what i wanted to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i guess you know that when num<<1 is executed,the num value will be doubled...
and the code you've written is perfectly working right,but you are analyzing it wrong.

while reading the input during run-time,you are reading from the last element through the first element.

So,in your inputs 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1
only a[0] and a[1] are one whereas all other a[i]'s are zero.

So,in

```
  for (i = 0;i < SIZE;i++) {
      if (x & a[ i ])
          sum = sum + (i << 1);
      else
          sum = (sum + 0); 
  }

 only the initial i values that are 0 and 1 are left shifted whereas all the others are ignored as all other elements except a[0] and a[1] are zero.
```

Therefore, in first iteration,   sum=sum+(0<<1)  ->  sum=0+0  ->  sum=0

in second iteration,  sum=sum + (1<<1)  ->  sum=0+2  ->  sum=2

further in all other iterations,the i values are not left shifted.so,the sum remains two.
Hence the answer you got is the right one....

Don't worry,you are the beginner now..you will make it some day...

Answer (score 0):

It looks you're shifting the wrong way. You should do `sum = sum + (1 << i)` rather than `sum = sum + (i << 1)`. The latter only multiplies by two (i.e. shifts 1 bit to the left) the index `i`.

That shifts 1 to the left according to the i-th position in the bitfield a. The following code should also simplify your code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define SIZE 8

int main() {
    int a[ SIZE ] = {0};
    int i;
    int sum = 0;
    for (i = (SIZE - 1); i >= 0; i--){
        scanf("%d", &a[ i ]);
    }
    for (i = 0;i < SIZE;i++) {
        if (a[ i ])
            sum = sum + (1 << i);
    }
    printf ("%d\n\n", sum);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To tell the truth, I can't get your point. You said "It returns to me the result of power of two of the index of the array." But you also mentioned left shifting. Which one do you want?

Anyway, is the following code what you want? I'll explain it in details if you say "Yes".

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define SIZE 8

int main() {
    int a[SIZE] = {0};
    int i;
    int sum = 0;
    for (i = (SIZE - 1); i >= 0; i--){
        scanf("%d", &a[i]);
    }
    for (i = 0;i < SIZE; i++) {
        if(a[i])
            sum += 1 << a[i];
    }
    printf ("%d\n\n", sum);
    return 0;
}
```